# disable chrome http request throttling in extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, throttling

how can i disable the anti ddos throttling inside a chrome extension? it is currently only working by set the flag `--disable-extensions-http-throttling`
inside the extension shortcut, but this is not acceptable when the extension is running on many clients (i would need to set it manually on any client).

I have tried to disable it in the background.js script, but it is not working:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(info) {
      var headers = info.responseHeaders;
      var throttleHeader = {name: 'X-Chrome-Exponential-Throttling',
          value: 'disable'};
      headers.push(throttleHeader);
      return {responseHeaders: headers};
    },
    {
        urls: ['*://*/*'], // Pattern to match all http(s) pages
        types: ['sub_frame', 'xmlhttprequest']
    },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

Are there any other ways to disable throttling for a extension? I am using the latest version of chrome (50.0.2661.102 m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely no way to disable throttling from within an extension. Allowing developers to do that would defeat the very purpose of throttling.

In fact the possibility to exploit the `X-Chrome-Exponential-Throttling` header for this purpose the way you just tried was considered a security issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318366

This eventually led to removing the `X-Chrome-Exponential-Throttling` header from Chrome in May 2015:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352259